# handling xml responses from httpclient in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, httpclient

I have this code.

```
hS = doHttpPost( Utility.removeNamespace(hlRQ.toString()), false,sSName, "Avty");
```

what this do is sending an xml created by code as hlRQ.toString() with creadentials so on.

i get `XmlObject hS` as result from the doHttpPost(is httpClient api) xml data.What i want is to handle the content of xml data that i get from hS.
Xml file has a lot of  data . Here is xml.

```
<Rate  Set="1"  ice="109.67">
        <Roate>
          <Req No="1"...........  Type="EXAMPLE"/>
        </Roate>
        <RoateInfo>
          <Child MinAge="0" MaxAge="0" Desc=""/>
          <Minstay MSDay="0.00" MSType="NONE" MSRate="0.00"/>
          ...
          ..
          .....
          <Comm  CommType="NONE" CommRate="0.00"/>
        </RoateInfo>
```

```
xml ........ goes on .....
```

for example i would like to parse it and get the value of    `<Roate>
              <Req No="1"...........  Type="EXAMPLE"/>
            </Roate>`
of `Type="EXAMPLE"` and get the EXAMPLE string or any other value form the xml.
I thought of creating a Map or some other data structure to add there  but i am not sure how to do it.Any help?
Thanks

Comment: You could parse it into a Document and use XPath. Or unmarshal it with Jaxb.

Comment: I have already try something like that i will try it again.

Comment: This is kinda a big problem to solve. http://programmers.stackexchange.com would be better for getting a high-level direction for what to do (though it might have to be framework and language-agnostic), stackoverflow is better for dealing with a specific issue. Try something, see how far you get, debug it, and if you're still having problems, ask about your specific problem.